# session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51)

Tags: python, selenium

Even though I have added options.add_argument("--no-sandbox"),options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") still I am getting session deleted of page crash issue . I have also increased the time.sleep values so that the browser doesn't crashes.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Is the problem of python or unsufficent disk storage on the instance